# Как определить какой checkbox выбран?

Tags: php, checkbox

Друзья! В цикле заполняю таблицу. В каждой ячейке по чекбоксу. Значения чекбоксов берутся из бд. В данной таблице проставляю нужные мне чекбоксы и сохраняю. Вопрос такой, как правильно мне отследить на каком поле я поставил галку? Если имя у чекбоксов я задаю исходя из итерации цикла. По сути имя могу любое дать, главное что бы я смог получить его посредством `$_POST['??']`.

В принципе, когда я делаю так:  `var_damp($_POST);` то я вижу все чекбоксы на которых стоят галки, но как мне в коде узнать в каком именно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Название checkbox-сов, уникализируйте.
Добавьте поле `hidden`, перед каждым checkbox-сом, таким образом у выбранных чекбоксов будет приходит их значение, у не выбранных значения hidden

```
<input type="hidden" name="item[uniqId]" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="item[uniqId]" value="1" />
```

Comment: в принципе да, можно так. Но если у меня 1000 строк в таблице, а изменил я только одну, как её определить? или полностью перезаписывать базу опять?

Comment: Разнице нет сколько строк в таблице, тут имеет значение сколько данных вы выводите на страницу. Перед каждым чекбохком добавьте поле input hidden, с одним значением, после сам чекбох. Если чекбох будет выбран, придет его значение, если нет, то значение hidden поля

Comment: @sbaikov обновил ответ

Comment: Daniyarov спасибо, что навели на умную мысль. На самом деле просто оказалось)

Comment: @sbaikov, "Но если у меня 1000 строк в таблице, а изменил я только одну" - и это хороший вопрос, только неправильно сформулирован изначально. Да и делается это в принципе немного по-другому. Если у вас много полей и они часто меняются небольшими пачками (например, по 1-10 штучек), то имеет смысл так и менять их - аяксом без использования классической формы отправки. Посмотрите, например, [jeditable](https://appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/). Я мало чего знаю из продвинутых штуковин таких - возможно сейчас модно каким-то другим плагином это делать.